# How to remove text character values from string on flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, replace

I would like to retrieve only the number values from a string on flutter without keeping the text hardcoded using replaceAll, the text can be anything but the number part of it has to be retrieved from it.

e.g.

```
String text = "Hello your number is: 1234";
String numberProvided = '1234';  // needs to be extracted from String text

print("The number provided is :" + numberProvided);
```

Like I said, the text characters shouldn't be hardcoded into the application, let me know if it is possible, thanks!

Comment: you want to print only numbers in text String?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil yes i want to retrieve only the number values from a string that includes both text and numbers

Comment: Check my answer hope its help to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the simple regular expression

```
    print(text.replaceAll(RegExp("[a-zA-Z:\s]"), ""));
```

Comment: Add trim at the end to avoid unnecessary spaces 
lile this :   print( text.replaceAll(RegExp("[a-zA-Z:\s]"), "").trim());

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you. refer `replaceAll` method [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html)

```
void main() {
  String text = "Hello your number is: 1234567890";
  var aString = text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), '');
  var aInteger = int.parse(aString);
  print(
    "The number provided is :" + aInteger.toString(),
  );
}
```

Your Output:

```
The number provided is :1234567890
```